# "Verify" pass in opt

Tags: llvm

I am trying to program llvm pass to do fault injection work to erroneously change control flow of program. Due to injected error in control flow, there are following error messages (I am not trying to find the reasons of error behind these messages, they are sort of injected intentionally):

PHI node entries do not match predecessors!
Instruction does not dominate all uses!

Through checking source code, I know these messages come from program called verifier.cpp. Looks like, it is the source code of "-verify" pass in opt. However, in my script, I do not include "-verify" pass in my command.

So, here are my questions:

1. Is verifier.cpp the source code of "-verify" pass?
2. If so, does "-verify" pass run automatically by opt regardless of whether you use it in option or not?
3. If 2 is right, is there any way to disable this pass (as I want to get the potential erroneous code for running experiment)?

Thank you.

Comment: i suggest taking a look at the results of `opt --debug-pass Structure`; there is a `-disable-verify` option in llvm-3.6.2. For more options, `opt --help-hidden`.

Comment: Thank you. I have find the option -disable-verify through --help-hidden. My llvm version is 3.4, but looks like that it works too.